# JavaScript: Keep Appended Text After Submit Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an HTML file that I cannot modify (assignment question requirement). My problem is the following: When I click on "Place Order" which is a "submit" type button, the text that needs to be appended to the existing one is correctly appended, but only stays there for a fraction of a second before disappearing. I know that it's because of the fact that the submit button refreshes the page, but I cannot modify the type to "button". Any way to fix this problem in the JavaScript document?

HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Exercise 4</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "PriceCalculator.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h2>Order Books Online</h2>
        <form action="" method="post" id=”frm”>
            <fieldset>
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Book</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Basic XHTML</td>
                        <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_1" /></td>
                        <td>$19.99</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Intro to PHP</td>
                        <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_2" /></td>
                        <td>$86.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Advanced JQuery</td>
                        <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_3" /></td>
                        <td>$55.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Place Order" id="sub" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript part:

```
function getButtonElement(){
    var button = document.getElementById("sub");
    button.addEventListener("click", calculatePrice, false);
}

function calculatePrice(){
    var b1 = document.getElementById("book_1").value;
    var b2 = document.getElementById("book_2").value;
    var b3 = document.getElementById("book_3").value;
    if (isNaN(b1) || isNaN(b2) || isNaN(b3) || 
        b1 == "" || b2 == "" || b3 == "" || 
        b1 == null || b2 == null || b3 == null ||
        /\s/.test(b1) || /\s/.test(b2) || /\s/.test(b3)){
        alert("Incorrect input, try again.")
    }
    else{
        var total;
        b11 = b1*19.99;
        b22 = b2*86.00;
        b33 = b3*55.00;
        total = b11+b22+b33;
    }
    var result1 = "Basic XHTML (Quantity = "+b1+"): $"+b11;
    var result2 = "Intro to PHP (Quantity = "+b2+"): $"+b22;
    var result3 = "Advanced jQuery (Quantity = "+b3+"): $"+b33;
    var result4 = "Final Total: $"+total;
    var p1 = document.createElement("p");
    var n1 = document.createTextNode(result1);
    p1.appendChild(n1);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(p1);
    var p2 = document.createElement("p");
    var n2 = document.createTextNode(result2);
    p2.appendChild(n2);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(p2);
    var p3 = document.createElement("p");
    var n3 = document.createTextNode(result3);
    p3.appendChild(n3);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(p3);
    var p4 = document.createElement("p");
    var n4 = document.createTextNode(result4);
    p4.appendChild(n4);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(p4);  
}

window.addEventListener("load", getButtonElement, false);
```

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to prevent the form's default behavior.

It'd be something like

```
var form = document.getElementById("frm")
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
})
```

That works for me - but I noticed an oddity with your html - the quotation marks on the form's id attribute are strange, so initially I couldn't access it with the above method without changing `id=”frm”` to `id="frm"`.

If you are absolutely not allowed to change the html (even to fix what looks to me like a typo), then you could get the element by another method, like `.getElementsByTagName` -

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
})
```

That'll do it.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help. I think it's true that there is a typo in the HTML file, so I corrected it. I just had another quick question, is it possible to replace the previously appended text with the new one if I enter new values in the text fields instead of appending a second text? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but the way that you have structured your JavaScript doesn't make it too easy.  I'd recommend that you create a <div> to hold all of your form output (all of the <p> elements) and then append this new div to `#container` rather than appending each <p> separately. When you submit the form, you'll need something like `if(resultsDiv){resultsDiv.innerHTML = ""}`. This would clear the contents of that div, if it exists. Put this conditional before the `event.preventDefault()`.